# FPS camera with y-axis limit to certain angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am starting a new game and right now my player can view 360* but I want to limit how far the player looks up in the sky and down (straight up and down).
Here's my code

```
Vector2 mouseLook;
Vector2 smoothV;

public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
public float smoothing = 2.0f;

GameObject player;

void Start () {
    player = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

    md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
    smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
    smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
    mouseLook += smoothV;

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
    player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, player.transform.up);
}
```

}

Comment: The player variable is the camera?

Comment: Yeah, the Player variable is the camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to do this. Below is what I use to rotate the camera up/down and left/right. You can modify the `yMaxLimit` and `yMinLimit` variables to the angles you want to limit it to. There should be no limit while moving in the `x` direction.

```
public float xMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;
public float yMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;

public float yMaxLimit = 45.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -45.0f;


float yRotCounter = 0.0f;
float xRotCounter = 0.0f;

Transform player;

void Start()
{
    player = Camera.main.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
    //xRotCounter = xRotCounter % 360;//Optional
    player.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Pogrammer, but there's a problem now, before with my code I was able to move the character to where the camera is point but just holding down 'w' but with your code, if I hold down the 'w' and move the camera the player will not move in the camera  direction e.g if I go forward and move the camera to the left it would not go to the left

Comment: This solution solves your looking/rotation limit problem not moving problem. Please create a new question for the moving problem and I will take a look at it. Make sure to post your moving code too.

Comment: Just did, I created a new question for the other problem