# Unity 3D - Limit Camera Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have found several awnsers to this question online, and I have tried all of them, but they either break my camera, or just overall don't work.

Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class fp : MonoBehaviour
{

public float speedH = 2.0f;
public float speedV = 2.0f;

private float yaw = 0.0f;
private float pitch = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
    yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
}
}
```

As far as I know, there is 3 solutions to this problem, but I don't know how to implement any of the solutions

Solution 1: Convert the script above to Unityscript (I have little expirience with C#) and I can solve the problem with "if" statements.

Solution 2: Provide the C# code to limit the angle on my script to an angle of 90 degrees all axis

Solution 3: All of the above

Comment: If you don't know how to do if statements in c#, you should focus in learning the basics first, give it a day or two.

Answer (score 3):

You don't post what you've tried, so this is a shot in the dark on helping you. Check [Unity's Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to restrict the angles allowed.

```
yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

yaw = Mathf.Clamp(yaw, -90f, 90f);
pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -60f, 90f);

transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I knew it was easy, I just didn't know how to do it...

Comment: "My script" works for the question asked. You didn't specify if game object changes. You asked how to limit camera rotation. Mark it as answered, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no attempt to limit any axis in your code. Use a temporary variable to limit your axis by incrementing it each tome `Input.GetAxis` changes. If it reaches the min or max value you want to limit it to then the `Mathf.Clamp` to clamp it between that min and max values/angle.

Modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361162/3785314) to limit your FPS camera in both axis instead of usual y-axis limit.

```
public float xMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;
public float yMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;

//Y limit
public float yMaxLimit = 45.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -45.0f;
float yRotCounter = 0.0f;

//X limit
public float xMaxLimit = 45.0f;
public float xMinLimit = -45.0f;
float xRotCounter = 0.0f;

Transform player;

void Start()
{
    player = Camera.main.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Get X value and limit it
    xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    xRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(xRotCounter, xMinLimit, xMaxLimit);

    //Get Y value and limit it
    yRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
    //xRotCounter = xRotCounter % 360;//Optional
    player.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);
}
```

Comment: This script was ineffective in my game

Comment: I did that. The script did not do anything