# Transform: mouse orientation not correct

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mouse

I have the following mouse code (C# with Unity) to rotate the camera with the mouse (x, y and z). But when I rotate the camera with the mouse, the camera moves with a offset.

```
void Update()
{
    Turn();
    Thrust();
}

void Turn()
{
    float yaw = turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");  //Horizontal
    float pitch = turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");  //Pitch
    float roll = turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Roll") //Roll
    transform.Rotate(-pitch, yaw, -roll) 

}
```

I want the camera move exactly with the movement of the mouse (just like a FPS). What is wrong with this code?

**EDIT**

Tried the solution from the duplicate. when I rotate the camera more than +/- 180 degrees over the x-axis than I got a problem with gimbal lock (left become right and right become left).

```
public class Movement002 : MonoBehaviour {

public float xMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;
public float yMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;

public float yMaxLimit = 45.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -45.0f;


float yRotCounter = 0.0f;
float xRotCounter = 0.0f;

Transform player;

void Start()
{

    player = this.transform.parent.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    //yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
    //xRotCounter = xRotCounter % 360;//Optional
    player.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);
}

}
```

Comment: It makes more sense to use `transform.localEulerAngles` than `transform.Rotate` for FPS like mouse control.

Comment: It gives a new problem: gimbal lock.  See also my other question about Gimbal Lock in Unity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347474/360-rotation-without-gimbal-lock-in-unity-with-c-sharp

Comment: Note that you did not use `transform.localEulerAngles` as I mentioned. You used `transform.rotation` and they are not the-same thing. Use the code from the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359972/fps-camera-with-y-axis-limit-to-certain-angle). It's an FPS code and no gimbal lock issue

Comment: OK, is this code also useable for 6DOF game (360 on x-, y- and z -axis)?

Comment: I don't know. This question has been marked as a duplicate and you have to try the duplicate yourself. Without trying it you won't know if it works or not. I noticed you are using `z` axis too, You may want to change `new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);` to `new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, roll);`.It also has an angle limit on the `y` axis but if you don't want it, simply remove `yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);`. That's it. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanx for your comments and code, but this also does not work (also gimbal lock problem). I think the problem is with the EulerAngles, but don't know how to solve.

Comment: Edit your question and post the current complete code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180576/discussion-between-johan-kornet-and-programmer).

Comment: Do not remove the original code. Add EDIT followed by the new code, I have reversed that. I have also re-opened the question since that did not solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I found your answer, [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/29741/mouse-look-script.html)
this page contains a class called mouselook, which is a unity asset you can get for free with the Unity Asset Demo Package. but you can just grab the script here if you wish.

a bit more on what your doing... it would be easier, from a programming perspective for you to put a script on the camera, which uses the `transform.lookAt()`

```
 Vector3 point = new Vector3();
        Event   currentEvent = Event.current;
        Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2();

        // Get the mouse position from Event.
        // Note that the y position from Event is inverted.
        mousePos.x = currentEvent.mousePosition.x;
        mousePos.y = cam.pixelHeight - currentEvent.mousePosition.y;

        point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane));
transform.LookAt(point);
```

you can put that on your camera and give it a whirl. it's important to note:

```
  mousePos.y = cam.pixelHeight - currentEvent.mousePosition.y;
```

because where converting from a screen point to a point in your world, and the mouses y is inverted in screen position so this flips it for you. good luck.

Comment: The mouselook script works perfect for the camera and Mouse, but it still has problems with gimbal lock. I want tot rotate more than 360 degrees (with no clamp/limitations), this give the problem. In the code with transform.lookAt(), I get a error because 'cam' isn't declared.

Comment: @JohanKornet You have to assign a camera to the script yourself.

Comment: Yes, I have assign a camera to the script.